# Emulating touch

Tags: android, event-handling, ontouch

We are trying to make a simple TeamViewer type application, where a touch on the local device will be emulated on the remote device. 
So how can the touch be emulated on the remote device ?
Conditions applied :
No root access

If emulating is not possible, is it possible to detect touch, i.e. to get the coordinates outside the application, if yes then how?
And also how to make a hollow floating widget? (such as a rectangle with only border, and touching the hollow part of rectangle is passed to the object beneath it) So that in case, touch is not emulated atleast the coordinate being touched is highlighted.